# Encrypt PHP module with SHA-256?

Tags: php, encryption

I have a WHMCS module and I am wondering if it's possible to encrypt it with SHA-256 or another form of uncrackable encryption.

I really know nothing about encryption but I want to ask is that possible? My plan is to encrypt it doing the following.

The top part of the script encoded with PHP > Ioncube will tell the script where to read the SHA-256 pass-phase either in a well hidden readable file or on our online servers. The rest of the script will be encrypted with three layers PHP > Ioncube > SHA-256.

Is that possible? If so would it slow the script down considerably?

Answer (score 2):

First: SHA-256 is a hash algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. If you indeed know nothing about encryption, it's probably best that you either learn more about it before embarking on an encryption-heavy project, or avoid it altogether.

More generally: What you're trying to do is possible in principle, but probably a bad idea. Existing PHP loaders such as Ioncube already take appropriate steps to try to prevent source recovery; piling on additional layers of your own design is likely to make it *less* secure, not more so. (In particular: putting an extra decode/eval phase inside IonCube will make it *trivial* to recover your source code using a debugger.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment duskwuff. I was just thinking :) I plan on paying for this to be done. What hashing algorithm would you suggest if I went ahead and done this? Ioncube alone is not enough.

Comment: That doesn't make sense as a question. A hash algorithm is used to generate a digest of data, not to encrypt it.

Comment: Ok what encryption? sorry I am not tech savy :(

Comment: The bigger question is: where are you going to store the encryption key? Without a trusted execution environment (TEE) you're only going to achieve obfuscation at best.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That doesn't even matter. Doing *any* kind of PHP code encryption in PHP is unsafe, as it's pretty easy to log the text passed to `eval()` in a debugger or extension.